# When will Litecoin be fully mined compared to Bitcoin? And at what years will each halving occur?

Tags: litecoin, mining-reward, reward-schedule

Bitcoin will be fully mined in about 100 years. When will Litecoin be fully mined for its 84 million? And in what year will each halving occur for Litecoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Litecoin block reward halves every 840,000 blocks, which is roughly every 4 years (block time of 2.5 minutes). The first halving to 25 LTC per block happened on 25 August 2015, and the next is predicted for August 2019, when the reward will halve to 12.5 LTC per block. So because litecoin halves as often as bitcoin, it'll be completely mined only a couple of years after bitcoin is

2015-08 -- 25.0 LTC

2019-08 -- 12.5

2023-08 -- 6.25

2027-08 -- 3.12

2031-08 -- 1.56

2035-08 -- 0.78

.... and every 4 years.